# Collecting strings from files and writing to an output file using Julia and Regex

Tags: regex, io, julia

(Julia and general programming newb)

I'm trying to read a directory full of JSON files containing lots of HTML pages (about 30), Regex match short strings (many per file, up to 60k total) and output these to one big file - which I'll try and parse later so I can add to a MySQL DB.

Here's my code:

```
patFilename = r"[0-9]+_[0-9]+.json"
patID = r"\/entry\/[0-9]+\/go"

filenames = readdir("C:/getentries/data/")

caseIDs = []

for filename in filenames
    if match(patFilename, filename) === nothing
        continue
    end

    file = open("C:/getentries/data/" * filename)
    case = read(file, String)

    push!(caseIDs, match(patID, case))

end

println(caseIDs)

touch("C:/getentries/data/caseIDs.txt")
open("C:/getentries/data/caseIDs.txt", "w") do caseID
    println(caseID, caseIDs)
end
```

No errors are thrown but only a few strings are written to the file. So I'm assuming something's going wrong as I try to collect all the strings.

I thought I could try the [approach suggested in my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65530350/scraping-string-from-a-large-number-of-urls-with-julia/65530655) but this didn't help - although that's likely due to my complete inexperience!

May I ask if anyone has any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say without a minimal, reproducible example. But my guess is that, since you're calling `match` once per file, you're only getting the first match in each file. Instead, you could call [`eachmatch`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/strings/#Base.eachmatch) to get an iterator over all matches in the file contents.

This would look something like the following:

```julia
for filename in filenames
    # Note that you forgot to close the file in your original example
    # Using higher-level functions such as this method of `read` may be safer
    str = read(filename, String)
   
    # Loop over all matches of the regexp found in the string
    for m in eachmatch(pattern, str)
        push!(matches, m)
    end
end
```

Comment: Yes I missed that close thank you! Also, I hadn't realised I can call read without opening the file. I'll need to look into this further thanks!